# Medial axis of symmetric solid & volume

Tags: geometry, volume, solid-geometry, solid-of-revolution

I have a problem and would appreciate some pointers. In short, I have a solid which is produced by revolving a 2D polyline around an axis, thus producing a solid of revolution. Now:

1) Is there some shortcut to computing its medial axis, by computing the medial axis of the 2D polyline?

2) If we put some lower bound to the sphere radii which are produced by the medial axis transform (thus approximating the solid), what is the volume produced, with respect to that lower radius?

Thanks!

Comment: How do you define a medial axis ? As the locus of centers of  included circles (in 2D) or spheres (in 3D) that are maximal ?

Comment: Yes. I think this is the standard definition.

Comment: But I think that in this case, you are speaking about the "skeleton" of your shape, and that the medial axis is extracted from the squeleton in a second step.

Comment: According to http://homepages.inf.ed.ac.uk/rbf/HIPR2/skeleton.htm , the MAT is the skeleton + the radius function. So, I would be happy to go with just the skeleton then.

Comment: The problem is that a polyline has no skeleton unless you close it and consider the skeleton of the shape obtained by filling its inside.

Comment: Well, it would make sense to take the polyline + its mirror image about the axis (on the same plane) + 2 potential line segments connecting the two, above and below (if the poyline doesn't meet the axis). Again, that would suit me fine.

Comment: In this case, the 3D skeleton looks to me as obtained by rotation of the 2D skeletton. But, as usual, 3D skeleton is rather difficult to manipulate (see the so-called $\alpha$-shapes).

Comment: It would make sense, but is there some formal proof? At the very least, I believe that the 3D skeleton would be a (rotated) subset to the 2D skeleton, but... proof?